# no as.matrix generic function

Tags: r, class, instantiation

In the R terminal I can issue

```
> as.matrix
function (x, ...) 
UseMethod("as.matrix")
<bytecode: 0x7ffd5430a898>
<environment: namespace:base>
```

I am trying to implement a class with a as.matrix method.  In my R package I have

```
as.matrix.pdist = function(x, ...) { do stuff ... }
```

When I install my package, I see

```
Creating a generic function for ‘as.matrix’ from package ‘base’ in package ‘pdist’
```

When I instantiate an instance of pdist and call `as.matrix`, my `as.matrix.pdist` method does not get called.  Does this imply as.matrix is not a generic function?  Why do I see the UseMethod call when I check the source of `as.matrix`?  How do I properly implement `as.matrix`?

Comment: My best guess is that you haven't exported your method...? Take a look at section 1.6.2 of [Writing R Extensions](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html).

Comment: Did you register the method in your namespace?

Comment: and you can make the "Creating a generic function" message go away by using `setGeneric`, as described in `?Methods`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, gotta add S3method(as.matrix, pdist) to the NAMESPACE file